# Editable UITextView with Text and image?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview, wysiwyg, core-text

One of my project requirement is to save data keyed in by the user. Which is text + image (they can attach image/video from photo album).

User should be able to edit the text in place (similar to ios mail.app), images can be inserted between texts and a delegate for taping image to provide image specific options.

I found few example to layout images and text with coretext but none of the coretext example I found are editable.

What kind of control should I use? How mail.apps and note taking app achieve this?

Comment: @LeoNatan it was helpful. But I'm in dilemma of using DTCoretext or webview contenteditable or other custom method. Right now, i am also working on workaround with multiple textviews. Anyways I'll accept your answer now.

Comment: Thanks. I can say that working with UIWebView with editable content is a pain in the butt, sadly. It just doesn't work well. It jumps around and scrolling is sporadic. That's strange, because UITextView is also implemented with WebCode (WebKit) internally, and using the private API `setContentToHTMLString:` puts HTML content in there and editing is suddenly a joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS5, the WebKit implementation now supports `contentEditable` and `designMode`. You can then edit HTML text inline and even embed images.

Comment: I'll see if I can use webview for my requirement. Share if you have any sample code.

Comment: You can see an example here:
http://ios-blog.co.uk/featured-posts/ios-5-rich-text-editing-series/

Comment: Thanks a ton leo. It is really a good resource.But as of now It doesn't handle tapping on image. I'll work on these stuff this weekend. Untill then I guess you are happy with a upvote.

Comment: You can wrap images in JavaScript and notify your app on clicks. Let me know how it goes.